# Getx onInit not calling

Tags: flutter, dart, splash-screen, flutter-getx

Any reason why app keep stuck on splash screen? I using getx state management. If authToken not empty, it should go to main page. But `onInit` in controller class not calling.

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/splashScreen',
      getPages: [
        GetPage(name: '/splashScreen', page: () => SplashScreen(),binding: Bind()),
        GetPage(
            name: '/login', page: () => LoginPage(), binding:Bind()),
        GetPage(
            name: '/mainPage', page: () => MainPage(), binding:Bind())
      ],
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        LocalizationDelegate(),
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en', ''),
        const Locale('zh', ''),
      ],
      title: 'Sample',
      theme: ThemeData(
        accentIconTheme: const IconThemeData.fallback().copyWith(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(headline6: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange)),
        primarySwatch: white,
        primaryIconTheme: const IconThemeData.fallback().copyWith(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      // home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

**Splash Screen**

```
class SplashScreen extends GetView<MainPageController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      height: 250,
                      width: 250,
                      child: Image.asset('assets/xxx.png')),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

**MainPageController**

```
class MainPageController extends GetxController {
  final con = Get.find<ProductDefectsController>();
  final con1 = Get.find<ProductQualityController>();
  final con2 = Get.find<ProductController>();

  var tabIndex = 0;

  @override
  void onInit() async {
    print("call onInit");  // this line not printing
    // checkIsLogin();
    // print("ww");
    super.onInit();
  }
}
```

**Bind**

```
class Bind extends Bindings {
  Repository? _repository;
 
  Bind() {
    final _service = Get.put(Service());
    final _db = Get.put(Db());

    final _dao = Get.put(Dao(_db));
    _repository = Get.put(Repository(_dao, _service));
  }

  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut<MainPageController>(() => MainPageController());  
    Get.lazyPut<LoginPageController>(
        () => LoginPageController(_repository!));
  }
}
```

---

**Edit**

I tried use `middlewares`, but I got error

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/splashScreen',
      getPages: [
        GetPage(
            name: '/splashScreen',
            page: () => SplashScreen(),
            binding: Bind(), middlewares: [GlobalMiddleware()]),
                ...
      ],
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      localizationsDelegates: const [
              ....
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**Middleware**

```
  class GlobalMiddleware extends GetMiddleware {
      final authService = Get.find<LoginPageController>();
    
      @override
      RouteSettings? redirect(String? route) {
        print(authService.isLogin.value);
        return authService.isLogin.value == true
            ? RouteSettings(
                name: "/mainPage",
              )
            : RouteSettings(name: "/login");
      }
    }
```

**Error**

```
"LoginPageController" not found. You need to call "Get.put(LoginPageController())" or "Get.lazyPut(()=>LoginPageController())"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to initialize your bindings somewhere before using/finding them. A good place is to provide an instance of your binding class (in your case `Bind`) to the `initialBinding` property of `GetMaterialApp`:

```
GetMaterialApp(
...
initialBinding: Bind(),
...
)
```

Then you can use the Middleware approach. But the controller approach may not work just yet because the controller instance isn't used on the page/view.
Remember a controller (or any other dependency) will get initialized (thus calling the lifecycle methods like `onInit`) only when the controller/dependency is used/called from the page/view. Which isn't happening in your case.

Comment: So how should fix?

Comment: That's what the answer says. I mean how to fix. Just follow that

Answer (score 0):

you need to instantiate your controller as in the example below

```
class HomeBindings implements Bindings {
      @override
      void dependencies() {
        Get.put(HomeController(influencerDataServices: Get.find(), cardsJobsServices: Get.find()));
        Get.lazyPut(() => AgendaCardsController(
            influencerDataServices: Get.find(), cardsJobsServices: Get.find()));
      }
    }
```

then in your route you need to call this binding, like this:

```
 List<GetPage> routers = [
        GetPage(
          name: "/home",
          page: () => const HomePage(),
          binding: HomeBindings(),
          transition: Transition.leftToRightWithFade,
          opaque: false,
          showCupertinoParallax: true,
        )
      ];
```

getx is tightly linked to controllers and bindings, you can also try on the page's on ready instead of on init

Answer (score -1):

You can delete that specific controller when you are going to that controller again by just adding these lines:

```
Get.delete<Yourcontroller()>();
Get.put(Yourcontroller());
```

In dependencies, this will solve the problem.

Answer (score -2):

I cant see in this code whether you used Get.put or Get.lazyPut. Make sure that you used one of them before using a Getx controller.

Comment: post edited..thanks

Comment: Ask for more information or suggest improvements on comment, please. Your suggest is not an answer.